# Wordpress wp_remote_post not working despite working API and increased timeout paramter

Tags: php, wordpress

Try to run a wp_remote_post method but keep getting the same timeout errors, not matter how many times I increase the timeout. The API works and is reachable and only takes about 3 secs to run. Here is what I have so far.

```
$options = array(
                'headers' => array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
                'method' => 'POST',
                'timeout'     => 45,
                'sslverify' => false,
                'body' => array('lname'=>$lname, 'fname'=>$fname, 'email'=>$email, 'course'=>'37', 'key'=>'someKet'));

        $api_return = wp_remote_post('https://my-api.net/api/add_user', $options);
```

Below is the error I get

```
object(WP_Error)#2460 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(80) "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Comment: Have you enabled  WP_DEBUG mode and checked php_errors ?

Comment: Perhaps the solutions in this ticket would be helpful [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154248/error-timed-out-with-succesfull-wp-remote-post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154248/error-timed-out-with-succesfull-wp-remote-post)

Answer (score 0):

Actually seen that body had a limit and had to add a `'Expect' => ''` to the header. For reference see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301451/wp-remote-post-doesnt-work-with-more-than-1024-bytes-in-the-body?rq=1